# What type of paint do you use for a concrete retaining wall to work with hydrostatic pressure?

Tags: walls, paint, outdoor, cement

I know we are not supposed to recommend brands because it is against the rules. But I am trying to paint some outdoor cement stairs that tie into a retaining wall that is roughly 4ft tall to as high as 7ft tall. We're on a hill so one side is higher than the other.

I just dealt with a HUGE fail at one of the main hardware stores where I learned later (after I paid $400 and painted several hundred square feet with the product I bought) that the type of cement paint I used isn't designed for vertical surfaces and retaining walls. It's partly my fault for not reading the entire label. But I did read the instruction portion thoroughly. And not only did I tell the HD rep at the store but a rep of the actual brand of paint I used was there today didn't speak up either. I showed everyone a photo of my cement wall and no one knew to steer me away. So now I'm not sure what type of paint to use.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you painting the side the water is coming *from*?  Or the side the water is trying to invade?

Comment: Water won't be in direct contact with it other than when it rains. I wound up ordering some DampLock online through the HD website. It's tintable and looks like it's going to meet my needs.